# What Is The Order Of Netstat Ports Displayed?

Tags: bash, shell-script, netstat

I display the port of certain process type for an environment using `netstat` and the `pid`

```
netstat -pant| grep LISTEN | grep 100452
```

There are always 2 ports for this process type (e.g. 8107 and 8112), so in my script I take the first one using `head`.

Up until now the first item has always been the lower port.
However, yesterday the higher port was the first.

I have fixed this in my script using `sort`, however, I would like to know what determines the order of the ports in the `netstat` output.

Is it related to when the port was opened?